# How to create a new html element on radio button change event?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In my html form I have 3 radio button for user to choose a room type

```
<input type="radio" name="room" id="standard" class="left" checked>Standard&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;           
<input type="radio" name="room" id="business" class="left">Business&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="room" id="suite" class="left last">Suite<br>
<div id="select"></div>
```

In my js file I want it so that when the user change the radio button it will add or show/hide the corresponding select input

my js for this currently is:

```
$(":radio").change( () => {
        const radioButton = $(":radio:checked").val();
        if (radioButton == 'standard'){
            var label = '<label>Select number of bed: </label>';
            var option = '<select class=bed><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>'
            var html = '';
            $("#select").html('');
            html += label;
            for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            html += option
            };

            $("#select").html(html);
        }
        else if(radioButton == 'business'){...}
```

Nothing change when I change the radio option, I'm a beginner so I don't know what/where went wrong

Comment: *so I don't know where [to start]* - start by adding some debugging against what you actually have vs what you expect.  For example:  `const radioButton = $(":radio:checked").val(); console.log("radioButton:", radioButton)` - should be a non-empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Your radio buttons have no value attribute so when you check the value you will not match with any of your options

```
<input type="radio" name="room" id="standard" class="left" checked value="Standard">Standard&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;           
<input type="radio" name="room" id="business" class="left" value="Business">Business&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="room" id="suite" class="left last" value="Suite">Suite<br>
```